# Rhombus Symmetry Group theory

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetry

I have a question about the permutations of the symmetry group of the rhombus. The rotational 2 symmetries are easy. I am unsure on the vertical and horizontal lines of symmetry. The corners that lie on the reflection line, are they reflected or do they remain the same - so are the 2 permutations in the image below correct or not ?

[image]

Comment: In both cases, your **second** solution is right: the vertical line reflection just transposes 2 and 4, keeping 1 and 3 intact. The horizontal line reflection just transposes 1 and 3, keeping 2 and 4 intact. The permutation $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2\end{pmatrix}$ is the *central symmetry* or, alternatively, *rotation by $180^\circ$*.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you! Yeah that makes sense, thank you : )

Comment: You could type that as an answer, @StinkingBishop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symmetries of a rhombus correspond in a certain sense to the symmetries of a non-square rectangle. Imagine the rectangle portrait. Simply label the top edge $1$, the righthand edge $2$, the bottom $3$, and the lefthand $4$. Then the symmetries are:

- **The Identity:** $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}.$$
- **Vertical:** $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
- **Horizontal:** $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}.$$
- **Rotational:** $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

These are precisely the symmetries you get using your notation for the rhombus. Can you see why?